# What does "Warning : There are multiple branch changesets here" mean?

Tags: git, jenkins

We use Jenkins as our CI-engine, which knows how to monitor a git repository.  For some reason I usually see

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/X/workspace
Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/X/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@844d88
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision 8422864a9745535d808435bd33ece764fd250358 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from gitosis@...
Seen branch in repository origin/HEAD
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Commencing build of Revision c1e71af117df3cd63da972f361ad260af6f16bf5 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Checking out Revision c1e71af117df3cd63da972f361ad260af6f16bf5 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Warning : There are multiple branch changesets here
Parsing POMs
Modules changed, recalculating dependency graph
```

My question is, what does the "Warning : There are multiple branch changesets here" line actually_mean_?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm no Jenkins expert but I found this issue that would seem to explain the warning:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-6856

It seems Jenkins builds in detached head state and that happens when it checkouts a remote branch (origin/master in this case) and I'm guessing that the warning is due to HEAD not pointing to a local branch. So Jenkins has created an anonymous branch in effect.

EDIT: Did a code search on Github and found the methods in the GitSCM plugin for Jenkins that generate this warning. See [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/GitSCM.java#L1300-1353)

If a [revision](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-client-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/Revision.java) (which you can see in another Jenkins plugin called git-client-plugin), has more than one branch pointing to it then the GitSCM plugin warns that there are multiple branches. The revision is the git commit that is being built and it is fully possible in git to have multiple branches pointing to the same commit.

The comment for the Revision class explains it:

> A Revision is a SHA1 in the object tree, and the collection of
>   branches that  share this ID. Unlike other SCMs, git can have >1
>   branches point at the  *same* commit.

Comment: Do you need more help? Such as identifying commits that are connected to multiple branches? Or anything that is missing about the explanation of the warning?